# How do i access a ref.current.value outside of the set scope

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, settimeout, ref

Here i have some React code ->

**React refs**

```
 const noteTitleRef = React.createRef();
 const noteBodyRef = React.createRef();
```

**Button component**

```
           <LoadingButton
                  color="secondary"
                  onClick={() => {
                    setLoading(true);
                      addNote(noteTitleRef.current.value, noteBodyRef.current.value);
                      setLoading(false);
                  }}
                  loading={loading}
                  loadingPosition="start"
                  startIcon={<SaveIcon />}
                  variant="contained"
                >
                  Save
                </LoadingButton>
```

If i change **Button component** to

```
           <LoadingButton
                  color="secondary"
                  onClick={() => {
                    setLoading(true);
                    setTimeout(() => {
                      addNote(noteTitleRef.current.value, noteBodyRef.current.value);
                      setLoading(false);
                    }, 1000);
                  }}
                  loading={loading}
                  loadingPosition="start"
                  startIcon={<SaveIcon />}
                  variant="contained"
                >
                  Save
                </LoadingButton>
```

Then the **noteTitleRef.current.value** & **noteBodyRef.current.value** becomes null and doesn't work.

How do i get around this? I would like to set a delay to my **onClick**, and after 1 second then i want the **addNote()** function to fire passing the **noteTitleRef.current.value**, **noteBodyRef.current.value** as parameters.

I appreciate all feedback!

Comment: It isn't clear why you think those refs would be anything other than null … nor is it clear why you are using refs instead of state in the first place.

Comment: where do you set your ref current values?

Comment: @ahmetkilinc   const addNote = (x, y) => {
    let notes = [...note];
    notes.push({ title: x, body: y });
    setNote(notes);
    
  };

Then onClick =  addNote(noteTitleRef.current.value, noteBodyRef.current.value);

Comment: @JoshHowarth To which input elements you are assigning those refs?